# Extract strings from character vector in R from/to specific words

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Here is an example of a character vector that I have, I need to extract all strings between "## Code:" and "## My table". I understand I can do this by position using `text[4:8]`, however the length of code to extract will vary so I need a solution that doesn't depend on fixed position.

`text <- c("## Author: user", "## Data = data.txt", "## Code:", "temp(){", "x = a1 + b1", "a1(b1 = 3)", "tf(cov = c(,1,))", "}", "## My table")`

The new character vector should contain this:
 `c("temp(){", "x = a1 + b1", "a1(b1 = 3)", "tf(cov = c(,1,))", "}")`

Thanks for helping me arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a logical index with `==`, and then wrap with `which`

```
text[which(cumsum(text == "## Code:"|text ==  "## My table") == 1)[-1]]
#[1] "temp(){"          "x = a1 + b1"      "a1(b1 = 3)"       "tf(cov = c(,1,))" "}"
```

Or with `which` find the start and end locations and use `:` to get the sequence of positions for extracting the elements

```
text[(which(text == "## Code:")[1] +1):(which(text ==  "## My table")-1)]
```